# Google Code Visualisation - setSelection in ChartWrapper

Tags: getselection, google-visualization

I am trying to connect google ChartWrapper Table selection with google Chartwrapper BarChart selection. Listener is working, but stops at:

```
orgchart.setSelection(table.getSelection());
```

(commenting this line runs next one).
I would be very grateful for any clues! It can be tested in [HTML section here](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#interaction_using_events).
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>
  Google Visualization API Sample
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['orgchart', 'table']});
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['barchart']});
  google.load('visualization', '1');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var table;
var data;

function drawOrgChartAndTable() {
  var test = [
    ['Name',  'Manager'],
    ['Mike',  1],
    ['Jim',   3],
    ['Alice', 4],
    ['Bob',   1],
    ['Carol', 5]
  ];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(test);

  var orgchart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'BarChart',
    dataTable: test,
      options: {'title': 'Countries'},
      containerId: 'orgchart'
    });
  orgchart.draw();

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
    dataTable: test,
      options: {'title': 'Countries'},
      containerId: 'table'
    });
  table.draw();

  // When the table is selected, update the orgchart.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {
    orgchart.setSelection(table.getSelection());
    alert("Table event!");
  });

  // When the orgchart is selected, update the table visualization.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(orgchart, 'select', function() {
    table.setSelection(orgchart.getSelection());
    alert("Chart event!");
  });
}


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawOrgChartAndTable);
</script>
</head>


<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="orgchart" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="table" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: It is the same problem than this discussion this https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-visualization-api/J3JmrdH4S8E/discussion

Answer (score 0):

(Uli's pointer to the solution is correct. Summarizing here, so this worthy question can be marked answered.)

Since 'select' events in the chartwrapper chart do not bubble up to the chartwrapper itself, you need to replace your references to table and orgchart with table.getChart() and orgchart.getChart().

And since you have to wait for both chartwrappers to be 'ready' before you can add the event listeners to their respective other charts, you have to do some trickery.  It might be simpler to wrap both charts in a dashboard and use one 'ready' event handler on the dashboard.